# identity of 2 lines from 2 files with same content in Python

Tags: python, iteration, identity, lines

I'm simultaneously reading lines from two text files with the same content (a word list).

```
peach
carrot
apple
lemon
```

I want to check whether the two simultaneous lines are identical. If they are not, the total similarity decreases. Since the two files are identical, checking for identity should lead to 100% similarity. Instead I get 0%.

```
from itertools import izip, izip_longest

with open(r'file1.txt', "rb") as f1, open(r'file2.txt', "rb") as f2:

    #initialize numerator & denominator values for calculating file similarity
    nTotal = 4 #total number of lines in each file
    nIdent = nTotal

    for line1, line2 in izip_longest(f1, f2):

        if((line1 is line2) is False):

            nIdent -=1

    similarity = nIdent/nTotal
```

Why are the lines not identical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparison `line1 is line2` is **not** the same as `line1 == line2`. The objects are **not** the same, but the data they represent is.

```
equal_lines = 0

with open(r'file1.txt', "rb") as f, open(r'file2.txt', "rb") as f2:
    for f1_line, f2_line in zip(f.readlines(), f2.readlines()):
        if f1_line == f2_line:
            equal_lines += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change:

```
if((line1 is line2) is False):
```

by:

```
if line1 == line2:
```

When you compare `string` objects in Python you can't use the `is` operator because in most of the interpreter implementation the same strings are represented as different objects **most of the time**.

`is` operator return `True` if the objects you are comparing are the same, not if the value of the objects are the same, being this last case what you need.

In some interpreter implementation strings literals with the same value could be ended implemented sharing the same object, but that is not a thing that you should trust in your scripts:

```
'abc' is 'abc' # True in CPython.
```

The above example is totally implementation depended and can vary in the future. You should compare immutable objects by its values, not by its object id (that is what `is` operator does).